# Update existing table of contents and table of tables officer r

Tags: r, ms-word, officer

Is there a way using officer to update an existing table of contents and table of tables with in my document? I know about the function `body_add_toc()` but is there a way to update these elements without having to recreate them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, TOC is beeing computed by Word. R does not know what content goes in what page. From what I know, the only way to achieve that would be a VBS Macro.

Comment: Thanks David that makes sense, I will rethink my set up in that case. Thanks for all your work, your packages have been a life saver.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware David is correct.

If you need to automate this process you can use the `update_toc(x)` function found in the `officerWinTools` R package.

The `officerWinTools` R package requires a Windows operating system with Microsoft Office installed (the functions of this package rely upon VBScript ran in Command Prompt).

The `update_toc(x)` function is also embedded in the `print_docx_pdf(x, target = "path")` function which will export a document created with the `officer` R package as a `.PDF` to a given path.

You can install the `officerWinTools` R package from GitHub:

```r
devtools::install_github("joshmire/officerWinTools")
```

Also, shout outs to David; your R packages have made my work much less of a headache.